# LXC: Are downloaded templates verified?

Tags: debian, security, lxc, verification

*Debian 8.3,
LXC 1:1.0.6-6+deb8u2*

When LXC downloads the base packages for a Debian container, are the packages verified? Verifying a Debian CD involves comparing signed checksum files against the checksum of the downloaded file (and also that the signature itself is valid) as described [here](https://www.debian.org/CD/verify). Apt also verifies packages automatically. Does the following LXC command download the base packages 'outside' of the apt system, making LXC a security weakness to the host with LXC installed?

```
lxc-create -n mycontainer -t debian
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `debian` template for `lxc-create` [internally uses](http://sources.debian.net/src/lxc/1:1.0.6-6%2Bdeb8u2/templates/lxc-debian.in/) `debootstrap` which [certainly verifies](http://sources.debian.net/src/debootstrap/1.0.67/debootstrap/) downloaded packages against [release signatures in the repository](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release) just like apt.